# What to do when your question gets closed as a duplicate, but you have no usable answer?

Tags: support, duplicates

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72219/how-do-you-introduce-someone-into-gming) question got closed as a duplicate. However, the "original" question is not same as mine, and has no usable answers. I tried editing my question, to make the difference more clear, but it seems like it didn't work, as it soon got closed.

My question is about guiding a new GM in his learning experience, while the "original" is about encouraging players to try DMing.

The two answers given are not satisfactory to me, but the question is closed now, so I won't get any new answers.

What do I do now? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Already looked at [Where do you defend / protest a closed question?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/981) and [My question is not answered there. How do I get rid of the blue banner?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5113)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing the question to explain the difference is the first step, and that step has not been successfully done yet.

Specifically, the paragraph you edited after the closure still doesn't sound like your question is different:

> I want to know how I should fulfill my tutoring role, I do not need advice on how to encourage the player even further, neither do I need advice for the player.

- What's the difference between *fulfilling a tutoring role* and *encouraging them to GM*? The average reader (myself included) probably doesn't see any difference between those two. If you do, you have to explain the difference. When the difference isn't explained by the question, the **main point** of your question is missing!
- How can you tutor someone *without* giving them advice? This part of your attempt to show the difference between the questions didn't work because it seems contradictory. Quite possibly there is a way that it *could* make sense, but whatever that might be, it's missing from the question.

Aside from the edit though, there is this:

> I am mainly interested in other's personal experiences, and possible blogs/articles on the subject.

As [we don't answer survey questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32153/153219) or [questions requesting lists](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/are-list-collection-questions-on-topic), making that the thing your question is “mainly interested in” guaranteed it would have been closed even if it wasn't a duplicate. Right now, even if you edited it to explain the difference in the questions, it would be reclosed as “too broad” because its central purpose is off topic.

In conclusion: It's still closed because the question needs a main point that isn't looking for a survey of experiences, and the question still needs to explain (in a way others will understand) what you see as the difference between the two questions or otherwise clarify why the answers to the other question don't solve your problem.

Whether an edit works to clarify a question is empirical: if it doesn't attract enough reopen votes to reopen, it didn't fix the problem that caused the closure. At that point you can edit further, or ask in chat / on meta / in comments for help understanding the specific issues with the question and how (and whether) they can be fixed.

Comment: I would just add that posting this meta is a great second step. This community wants to help you find the best solution it can to your problem. Sometimes that means working with you (in comments and in meta) to clarify a question first. Sometimes it means helping you find a place to ask your question that will be better-suited to meeting your needs than we are. The process of [hold, comments, edits, votes, more comments, more edits, &c.] may seem cumbersome, but the quality of answers that brought you here is the proof that it works =)

Comment: Wondering if your main point will be clear to readers is like wondering if your self-made puzzle/riddle will be too easy/hard. I tried to edit the question again, hoping it can be re-opened. Any extra critique is certainly welcome.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I could encourage someone to GM by telling them "*I'll give you free pizza if you GM this session.*" Or even "*I'll hit you with this stick if you* don't *GM this session.*" Or even just "*Trust me, GMing is fun! Just try it!*" None of those seem like "tutoring" to me; they may convince the person to try GMing, but they won't help him/her GM any *better*.